# Resource recommendation for studying Elastostatics and Elastodynamics using Lagrangian and Hamiltonian formulation

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, resource-recommendations, hamiltonian-formalism, continuum-mechanics, solid-mechanics

I've been self studying Elastostatics and Elastodynamics from Kip S. Thorne's Modern Classical Physics (Chapter 11 & 12). The whole topic is discussed based on Newtonian mechanics, vector & tensor analysis. I was wondering if there's any text where the topic is developed using Lagrangian and Hamiltonian formalism. I've also seen Landau's vol-7 Theory of Elasticity which treated the topic in same manner as Thorne.

My primary goal was to study Solid Mechanics, but now I'm just wondering aimlessly. It'd be very helpful, if anyone also provide some suggestions for studying Solid Mechanics using Lagrangian and Hamiltonian formalism. TIA.

Comment: It seems that you can start from de Gennes book "Physics of Liquid crystals". This books is full of interesting examples. Then, R. Jones "Soft condensed matter" will be good aid in your study. I believe that many examples of lagrangians and hamiltonians from these books provide a good background for study of more complicated/different problems